# Hadoop put vs copyFromLocal

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Still i am confused what is the difference between put and copyFromLocal. A lot forum and blog convey that both are same and nothing difference. May be you have some better idea and which stand point it differ. I am learning and executing Hadoop command from CDH5. 
i did some tricky commands and both commands are executed fine.

```
[cloudera@quickstart Desktop]$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/emp.txt /;
[cloudera@quickstart Desktop]$ hadoop fs -put file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/emp.txt /;
```

Comment: Still i am NOT clear.. duplicate response. Hence raised new one to get better idea with commands

Comment: Whatever answers would  be written here should be written there instead. You can also read the Hadoop CLI documentation on the optional flags both support. The default behavior is both operate the same